How does one convert a C pointer-to-pointer to a Rust slice of slices?
Say I have a C float**, which I index in C like float[x][y].
Is it possible to pass that float** to Rust and convert it to an &mut [&mut [f32]] so I can handle it more "rustily" within Rust?
It wasn't too complicated to convert an one-dimensional array pointer using std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut, but I'm completely stumped on how to do the same with a two-dimensional array pointer without angering the borrow checker or incurring unnecessary allocations...

The most you can possibly do by just converting the pointer itself is &mut [*mut f32]. This is because of two facts about the Rust types involved:

Rust slice pointers contain lengths. That is, an &mut [f32] has more information than just the address of the f32 data — more information than C stores.
Rust slices are contiguous sequences of elements (like C arrays). If you have an &mut [T] then there must be some location in memory where Ts are stored adjacent to each other.

What you get from C is described in Rust syntax as *mut *mut f32. This pointer points to a contiguous sequence of just addresses (pointers) — no lengths. Therefore, you do not have a [*mut [f32]], which would have both addresses and lengths; only an [*mut f32], with addresses only. Since you don't have an [*mut [f32]] anywhere, you definitely can't construct an &mut [*mut [f32]].
You have two choices:

Perform the allocation you didn't want to do — build a Vec<&mut [f32]> with the appropriate lengths for each inner slice, and return that.
Instead of trying to produce an [&mut [f32]] of any sort, write a custom wrapper type around the pointer, with a method or std::ops::IndexMut implementation that produces &mut [f32]s on demand. Or, write an iterator which returns &mut [f32], if you only need sequential rather than random access.

The good news is, option 2 is perfectly good idiomatic Rust! Even in pure Rust code with no FFI involved, you shouldn't use &mut [&mut [f32]], because it almost always demands a temporary allocation to hold the inner &muts.

Thank you for the super detailed and easy to follow answer! I assumed &mut [&mut [f32]] was the way to go, but option 2 seems to be the better way... since I only need sequential access, I was originally accessing the values with *(*float_arrays.add(x)).add(y), but that felt too "C-like" and I thought there must be a more idiomatic way. Writing an iterator feels somewhat similar to that, but would it be considered better practice than raw pointer offsetting/dereferencing?

@arghhh In general, writing less unsafe code is always a good plan. Once you have one of the inner pointers in hand, you can convert it to an &mut [f32] (presuming you know the length by some means), and then instead of doing any unchecked pointer arithmetic at all, all the rest of the work can be handled by a standard slice reference or a slice iterator. It's only the outer part that may need a custom iterator.

Thanks for the clarifications! I'm now struggling to write a wrapper + iterator/method that doesn't involve neither keeping the array length+iterator position stored (= albeit small, extra allocations) nor pointer arithmetic to get the desired inner pointer. Is that possible at all, or would it already be "best effort" to just accept the length storage/pointer arithmetic there? (I get the feeling it's a tradeoff between a. store length+current iterator position, but get extra safety in return; or b. pointer arithmetic all the way, no safety but tiny performance gain. Would that be right?)

@arghhh Sorry, but I can't tell from your description what your situation actually is — in particular, you haven't said anything about where the length information comes from. Consider posting a new question with details on that — comments are not the appropriate place for followup problems.

Oh my, you're right, sorry about that. Here's the new question, for future reference.
